# Unable to connect to ADB - Connect ADB using CMD, Wireless App debug testing

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-studio-3.0

If you want to run an Android application without using a USB wire. Then you can configure your device with android studio using the command line. Here are the steps to connect your Android device to your android studio through the same wifi.

Open your command line and...

D is the directory where your Android SDK is stored.

```
cd D:\Android\SDKs\platform-tools
```

Open wifi network and check your IP then paste in the command line

```
adb connect 192.168.1.101:5555
```

If the device is not connecting and you have an issue then run `adb tcpip 5555`.

The final steps are

```
cd D:\Android\SDKs\platform-tools
adb connect 192.168.1.101:5555
adb tcpip 5555
```

Answer (score 10):

I was also facing this issue in android Studio 3.4 version, but now I have fixed it , if you are using windows then follow these steps:

Download Platform tools from here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.0-windows.zip

Extract downloaded zip file

Go To location "C:\Users\your_computer_user_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" and Delete "Platform tools" folder

Copy and Paste, downloaded platform tool folder to above location

Now Go to your android studio and Rebuild your project Then run.

also check if you had open emulator from visual studio then emulator from android studio wont work here .

Comment: very important for me was to create a new device instance after doing this. Was trying to solve this issue for hours but using a new VD was solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

the adb.exe in path sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe is damaged. 
try re-extracting it from sdk or just downloading the adb.exe with 2 other .dll supporting files. That should solve the problem